# Integrating SweetAlert2 to Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, sweetalert, sweetalert2

Per https://sweetalert2.github.io/ I downloaded a copy of sweetalert2.all.min.js from https://www.jsdelivr.com/package/npm/sweetalert2. Since in background.html I'm not able to use the URL due to Chrome Extension I am using a local copy instead. Here is my background.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <script type="module" src="sweetalert2.all.min.js"></script>
  <script type="module" src="background.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

I try to use SweetAlert2 in background.js which is here:

```js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
      console.log("request=" + request);
      var notificationType
      if (request.charAt(request.length - 1) == 'N')
        notificationType = request.substring(0, request.length - 1) + " notes!";
      if (request.charAt(request.length - 1) == 'W')
        notificationType = request.substring(0, request.length - 1) + " watches!";
      if (request.charAt(request.length - 1) == 'C')
        notificationType = request.substring(0, request.length - 1) + " comments!";
      Swal.fire("Incoming!", "You\'ve got " + notificationType, "info");
```

But I receive [this error in Chrome Extension:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0kuVh.png) "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'Sweetalert2' of undefined" and it shows the code in sweetalert2.all.min.js that I downloaded.

Here are other important parts of my Chrome Extension

Manifest:

```
{
    "name": "Notifier",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "Notifies you when you get an FA notification!",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "background": {
        "page": "background.html",
        "persistent": false
    },
    "permissions": [
      "activeTab",
      "notifications"
    ],
    "browser_action": {
        "default_popup": "popup.html",
        "default_icon": {
            "16": "FA icon.png"
        }
    },
    "icons": {
        "16": "FA icon.png"
    },
    "content_scripts": [
   {
     "matches": ["http://*.website.net/*"],
     "js": ["sweetalert2.all.min.js","jquery-3.3.1.min.js","contentScript.js"]
   }
 ]
}
```

And contentScript.js:

```js
if ($('a[title="Note Notifications"]').length) {
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage($('a[title="Note Notifications"]').text());
}
if ($('a[title="Comment Notifications"]').length) {
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage($('a[title="Comment Notifications"]').text());
}
if ($('a[title="Watch Notifications"]').length) {
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage($('a[title="Watch Notifications"]').text());
}
setTimeout(function() {
  window.location.reload(1);
}, 30 * 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

its because of the module attribute in the html code

i'm sure someone will explain exactly why as i'm not exactly an expert

i tested this and it worked:

```html
<script src="sweetalert2.all.min.js"></script>
```